# Django form : Setting the user to logged in user

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to create an address book website where logged in user is able to fill in a form and store contact information. I was able to implement the login and logout functionality. But the problem is that I am not able to set the username to current logged in user. Here is what I have implemented so far:

Models.py

```
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True)

    #additional

    def __str__(self):

        return self.user.usernname

class UserContacts(models.Model):

    current_user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    email_address = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length = 350)

    def __str__(self):

        return '{}'.format(self.first_name)
```

Forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    password = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ('username','email','password')

class UserContactForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta():
        model = UserContacts
        fields = "__all__"
```

views.py:

```
@login_required
def new_contact(request):


    form = UserContactForm()

    current_user = request.user.get_username()
    user = User.objects.filter(username=current_user).first()
    output = UserContacts.objects.filter(current_user_id=user.id).first()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserContactForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return index(request)
        else:
            print('Error Form Invalid')

    return render(request,'basic_app/contact.html',{'form':form})
```

Here is how the output looks like when the logged in user tries to enter contact information details:

[Updating contact screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ig6c.png). As you can see the current user has to select his username to fill out the contact information.

How to overcome this and by default set the username in the form to the current logged in user

Answer (score 0):

Change your `UserContactForm` to include an extra perameter in `__init__`, and set the initial value on the `user` field:

```
class UserContactForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta():
        model = UserContacts
        fields = "__all__"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kws):
        # To get request.user. Do not use kwargs.pop('user', None) due to potential security hole
        self.user = kws.pop('user')
        super().__init__(*args, **kws)
        self.fields['user'].initial = self.user
```

Then change you view to add in the `request.user` to the form construction:

```
@login_required
def new_contact(request):


    form = UserContactForm(user=request.user)

    current_user = request.user.get_username()
    user = User.objects.filter(username=current_user).first()
    output = UserContacts.objects.filter(current_user_id=user.id).first()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserContactForm(request.POST, user=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return index(request)
        else:
            print('Error Form Invalid')

    return render(request,'basic_app/contact.html',{'form':form})
```

You could probably remove the:

```
    current_user = request.user.get_username()
    user = User.objects.filter(username=current_user).first()
    output = UserContacts.objects.filter(current_user_id=user.id).first()
```